# dataTables new row won't add to table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, datatables

When I add new data it won't add to table

[image: one]

## Code

`HTML`

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">ID</th>
            <th class="text-center">Number</th>
            <th class="text-center">Body</th>
            <th class="text-center">Heading</th>
            <th class="text-center">Book</th>
            <th class="text-center">Chapter</th>
            <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template v-for="verse in getVerses">
            <tr v-bind:key="verse.id">
                <td width="30" class="text-center">{{ verse.id }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ verse.number }}</td>
                <td>{{ verse.body }}</td>
                <td>{{ verse.heading }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ verse.book.name }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ verse.chapter.name }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button" @click="deleteVerse(verse.id)">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`Script`

```
export default {
    name: "adminVerses",
    data() {
        return {
            isLoading: true,
            type: '',
            books: [],
            errors: [],
            pageTitle: 'Manage Verses',
            getChapters: [],
            getVerses: [],
            isLoadingChapters: true,
            isLoadingVerses: true,
            verse: {
                number: 1,
                heading: '',
                body: '',
                book_id: '',
                chapter_id: '',
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit: function(e) {
            axios.post('/api/saveVerse', this.verse)
            .then(res => {
                this.isLoading = false;
                $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
                this.getVerses.push( res.data.verse );
                this.verse = {
                    number: parseInt(this.verse.number) + 1,
                    heading: '',
                    body: '',
                    book_id: this.verse.book_id,
                    chapter_id: this.verse.chapter_id,
                };
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // handle authentication and validation errors here
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors
                this.isLoading = false
            })
        },
    }
}
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

by adding

```
if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#verses')) {
  $('#verses').DataTable().clear().destroy(); //This will destroy datatable               
};

this.getVerses.push( res.data.verse );
```

now i can get my newly added data into my table but i also will lose ability of paging and search, etc.

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are using **this** to refer to an object, so you are limited to Axios scope. Instead you can use a variable to store a reference to main object, in your case adminVerses and then use $data to set or fetch the data attributes.

Example :

```
    let vm = this;
axios({
                ...
            }).then((res) => {

                vm.$data.getVerses.push( res.data.verse );
            });
```

Comment: what is `$data`? isn't my `res` fetching data?

Comment: $data is the property of Vue to access the data attribute from methods. Can you screenshot the vue debug console and check if the data is set? And can you manually set the value of getVerses  after your axios request to verify if it setting the value properly like this vm.$data.getVerses = { .. some object ... }

Answer (score 0):

open your vue devtools and check if getVerses gets the right data

Comment: maybe you can use this.$forceUpdate() after pushing your data

Comment: already others suggested that and tried it, didn't work as it should

Answer (score 0):

The push on the array isn't responsive, so the vue doesn't know it needs to update the view. The array setter is responsive, so:

```
this.getVerses = this.getVerses.concat(res.data.verse)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't, maybe i need to destroy table?

Comment: Hmm.  I wouldn't know how to destroy the table.  Surprised that the setter didn't work.  Even though this shouldn't remain in your code, can you add this `vm.$forceUpdate();` after the push. See what happens

Comment: i've updated my question would you check it please?

Comment: `this.$forceUpdate();` will also add the update to my table but same as my update part it has pagination and search issue